# At what point does ping make LoL almost unplayable?

Tags: league-of-legends

I ask this question so that I can use it to my advantage.

At what point does ping become an issue for a player?

This would help me know (as a jungler for instance) who to help (gank bot more) or who to attack (gank an opposing player more)

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close your question as "Not Constructive." This depends greatly on the person in question, and the skill level of the people in the match. There is just no way for us to provide a concrete answer to this question, and will just come down to personal opinion.

Comment: To further @Wipqozn point, This also depends on other player's latency, and also requires knowledge of how Riot has implemented its network protocols.  Latency is just a measure of trip time.  As an example, Riot may notice my latency is high and increase the data sent but reduce the number of times it sends/updates the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200 is already pretty annoying. I guess from 150 on you have an clear advantage over the other guy (harder to dodge/land skillshots) and after 450-500 it gets unplayable.

Answer (score -2):

Its playable (passable) from 700 and below, but you have to be able to guess early what is about to happen. Above that and you might as well try to park on a slope without a handbrake.

I've personally played games at 1000ping, and I know that at Denny's my friend got 12K. Terrible. Never play LoL at a restaurant. They probably livestream... something... in the back room.

Comment: 12k, as in 12 secs ping?!

Comment: uhm I think that one was latency, sorry. We did the math, it was nearly 2 minutes ping.